# /usr/sib/sshd: relocation error: symbol EVP_KDF_ctrl version OPENSSL_1_1_1b not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference

Tags: openssl, sshd

for years and years i do visit stackoverflow and now... and now i have a problem i cant solve without asking: 
my openssh server (at centos8) wont start (with mentioned error) anymore since i moved and relinked a self-compiled openssl onto it 
(thats why i cant just simply copy+paste some console outputs, i need to write them down manually)

openssl compile config:
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl --openssldir=/opt/openssl no-weak-ssl-ciphers '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)' shared zlib

i created a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf with:
/opt/openssl/lib

i created a executable file in /etc/profile.d/openssl.sh with:
pathmunge /opt/openssl/bin

i moved the original openssl executable:
mv /bin/openssl /bin/openssl.backup

...and created a symlink:
ln -s /opt/openssl/bin/openssl /bin/openssl

ldd $(which sshd) | grep crypto gets me:
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (hex-stuff)

it breaks when i configure the new so in /etc/ld.so.conf.d and execute ldconfig

ofc i googled it, but i couldnt find helpfull informations, except "use installed openssl"

i really dont know where to look anymore, please help... i hope the given informations are exhaustive enough.

i apologize for my bad english, im not a native speaker...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by building the latest libssh.so and installed it in /user/local/lib64 and then created the soft link libssl.so and libssl.so.4 in the /usr/lib64.

And More importantly

exported the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with /usr/lib64 as its first entry. If some other path is coming before /usr/lib64 and it has a different version of libssl or libcrypto that it will result in this error.